# What is the difference between =~ and match() when pattern matching?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-1.9.3

I am using `Ruby 1.9.3`. I was playing with some patterns and found something interesting:

Example 1:

```
irb(main):001:0> /hay/ =~  'haystack'
=> 0
irb(main):003:0> /st/ =~ 'haystack'
=> 3
```

Example 2:

```
irb(main):002:0> /hay/.match('haystack')
=> #<MatchData "hay">
irb(main):004:0> /st/.match('haystack')
=> #<MatchData "st">
```

`=~` returns the first location of its first match, whereas `match` returns the pattern. Other than that, is there any difference between `=~` and `match()`?

***Execution time difference***   ***(As per @Casper)***

```
irb(main):005:0> quickbm(10000000) { "foobar" =~ /foo/ }
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   8.530000   0.000000   8.530000 (  8.528367)
--------------------------- total: 8.530000sec

       user     system      total        real
   8.450000   0.000000   8.450000 (  8.451939)
=> nil

irb(main):006:0> quickbm(10000000) { "foobar".match(/foo/) }
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
  15.360000   0.000000  15.360000 ( 15.363360)
-------------------------- total: 15.360000sec

       user     system      total        real
  15.240000   0.010000  15.250000 ( 15.250471)
=> nil
```

Comment: Why down vote i am given?

Comment: Both the `operator` and `method` might be doing the same thing, but they are too much different in their functionality - both the post carries too much information and which is really awesome and helpful knowledgeable information for all SO users. In-spite of all these I am getting down vote means really bad for me! I didn't expect that this from the forum.

Comment: I did not downvote you, but I suppose it is because the question as written is moderately nonsensical. You found that there is more than one method that does something similar, but that each returns different results. Why is this interesting? There are many methods in Ruby (and most programming languages) that do similar things but return different results.

Comment: @Phrogz the interesting things comes out from my post to the answers of both. there are the information which has been extracted from the users to SO, due to my post. And the answers are not for me only. it is for all SO followers!

Comment: @Phrogz It would be interesting if the OP were expecting them to do the same thing (as is the case of, e.g., `String#==` and `String#eql?`). The answer could certainly have been found with more research, but it is a fair beginner's question.

Comment: And the question is not whether it's interesting (which is subjective), but what the differences are between the methods.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard `+1` to your comments!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First make sure you're using the correct operator: `=~` is correct, `~=` is not.

The operator `=~` returns the index of the first match (`nil` if no match) and stores the `MatchData` in the global variable `$~`. Named capture groups are assigned to a hash on `$~`, and, when the `RegExp` is a literal on the left side of the operator, are also assigned to local variables with those names.

```
>> str = "Here is a string"
>> re = /(?<vowel>[aeiou])/    # Contains capture group named "vowel"
>> str =~ re
=> 1
>> $~
=> #<MatchData "e" vowel:"e">
>> $~[:vowel]    # Accessible using symbol...
=> "e"
>> $~["vowel"]    # ...or string
=> "e"
>> /(?<s_word>\ss\w*)/ =~ str
=> 9
>> s_word # This was assigned to a local variable
=> " string"
```

The method `match` returns the `MatchData` itself (again, `nil` if no match). Named capture groups in this case, on either side of the method call, are assigned to a hash on the returned `MatchData`.

```
>> m = str.match re
=> #<MatchData "e" vowel:"e">
>> m[:vowel]
=> "e"
```

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html (as well as the sections on `MatchData` and `String`) for more details.

Comment: `+1` to you!Your findings are perfect,understood! but still confusion i am having about the `hash` what you are trying to say! could you explain that with a code or something else - so that your thought can be visible to me! please

Comment: @DoLoveSky Edited with some output using irb.

Comment: @DoLoveSky I highly recommend you read through the ruby docs referenced in my answer. There is a lot more information there that could be very helpful.

Comment: Yes sir :) I am doing that right now. I just loved the two answers in my post!

Answer (score 4):

<strike>When you have a method that does not modify state, all that matters is the return value.  So what's the difference between red and blue, besides color? My point is that this is kind of a strange question, one which you seem to already know the answer to.</strike> (@sawa set me straight here)

But that said, both methods return `nil` (a falsy value) when the regex does not match. And, both methods return a truthy value when it does match. `=~` returns an integer that represents the first character of the match, and even if that is `0`, because `0` is truthy in Ruby.  `match` returns an object with very detailed match data, which is handy when you want lots of info about the match.

`=~` is typically used in conditionals, when you only care *if* something matches:

```
do_stuff if "foobar" =~ /foo/
do_stuff if "foobar".match(/foo/) # same effect, but probably slower and harder to read
```

`match` is typically used when you want details about what was matched:

```
 name = "name:bob".match(/^name:(\w+)$/)[1]
 puts name #=> 'bob'
```

Comment: `+1` to you! great explanation.Lot's of information you have provided to me. thank you very much!

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph alone. (And the rest is good, too. :)

Comment: All that matters is not only the return value. There is another thing: the speed. It is in principle possible (although it is not actually the case) that `match` does more extensive calculation than `=~` so that may be one factor in deciding which to use. It is not a strange question. I don't think your red vs. blue argument makes any sense.

Comment: @AlexWayne I would like to say you once again thank you very much for bringing out the most valuable points in your post!!

Comment: Anyone interested I did a very simple benchmark with `=~` vs `match`, and found `=~` to be almost twice as fast as `match`: http://pastie.org/5690542

Comment: From Ruby 2.4 (~2016) I believe it is now faster to use `match?` over `=~` in the conditional case: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8110